# voice call using twilio to my personal number

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, voice

I am creating `Swift` app from which user can able to do call from `Twilio` number to personal number and for that i have implement code as below which i have referred from `Twilio` documentation here is the reference link

[This is the code which i have used in my app](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/making-phone-calls-in-swift-with-twilio.html)

but now issue is that call is receiving to my personal number but i am to able to talk with another person who is receiving call and when call is received from personal number than i can able to here `TWIML Bin` content which i have added as.`XML` format as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Response>
  <Say>This is the demo for Call And SMS</Say>
  <Dial>+15005550006</Dial>
</Response>
```

so Outgoing call is from `+15005550006` and receiving from my personal number then only i can here is that  tag text i am not able to talk like we talk on normal voice call through network carrier so can anyone have idea how to connect call when i receive call from my personal number

if any one have idea that how to connect call from twillio number to personal number using `Swift` than kindly tell so i can able to solve this

Comment: Is the +15005550006 an example number? This is a special number for Twilio and should not be used for actual calls, https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/04/twilio-test-credentials-magic-numbers.html. You example, the outbound call is to `+15005550006` not from that number. You must use your actual Twilio credentials, not test credentials when making calls.

Comment: yes its just an example number i am try with another number in my code

Comment: Are you calling a destination you authorized in your Voice Geographic Permissions, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180228-International-Voice-Dialing-Geographic-Permissions-Geo-Permissions-and-How-They-Work

Comment: i don't have issue with Geographic Permissions my call is successfully dialed but when i am receiving call from my phone then i am not able to communicate like we did in normal voice call

Comment: in sort i am trying implement feature like normal voice call as we did through network carrier only difference is that i am call through the my app to personal numbers

Comment: Anything in you debugger? You will need to set callerId since Clients don't use E.164 phone numbers, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#callerid. THe callerId must be either a Twilio number in your account or a Verified Caller ID - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio.

Comment: @Alan We have already purchased number from twilio and i am using that number for calling through app

Comment: Adjust your TwiML (the XML you show in your post) to have the callerid parameter as shown in the URL I posted.

Comment: @Alan yes i have tried as shown in url but still i am not able connect call and not able communicate with the person who receiving the call

Answer (score 0):

[This Code](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/making-phone-calls-in-swift-with-twilio.html) which you have used to make the call is only made for MAKING the call and NOT handling the actual communication after the call has been connected.
To be able to have a proper VoIP or conventional call using your twilio purchased phone number to your courier based phone number, you have to first make the swift app using the TwilioVoiceSDK, the code you have mentioned was only doing an HTTP request with parameters to invoke an outgoing call, but with twilioVoiceSDK you will not only invoke the code but will also be able to handle the actual communications after the call gets connected.
[TwilioVoiceSDK](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-ios) look into this to get further explanation of the whole system.
Secondly you will also need to code in TwiML bin or twilio cloud to handle the outgoing calls to actual phone number as well, which you can also check from the above link.

Coming back to this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Response>
  <Say>This is the demo for Call And SMS</Say>
  <Dial>+15005550006</Dial>
</Response>
```

This will convert the text to speech and the dials the specified number, The caller will hear the text and the call will initiate and thats it.

> This is the demo for Call And SMS